# Windows embedded 2009 service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-embedded

I'm developing an application that will be executed in a ThinClient with Windows Embedded 2009. It's written in C# 3.5. But, when I played for the first time with the ThinClient, I noticed that it has a lot of features disabled.

For example, there is no MyPc, or I can't have access to it.

So, my app needs to run when the client is turned on, but I can't find a service manager in embedded 2009.

Is there a way to make my app run every time the client is turned on?, I thought about a service, with automatic start. Can this be done like a windows service with no problems?

And another thing. My app also has to shut down the client. I've found a way to make it, but, I'd like to know if is different in Wndows Embedded.

Btw, the device has no hard disk.

Any other suggestion, will be very appreciated.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the older Embedded there is a "startup"-folder (located on the flash-card containing the win-image)

Comment: Thanks! The problem was solved, as a WYSE(R) ThinClient it has writing filter enabled, that was the reason I cannot do anything. Once disabled the filter, I've placed my app in the startup folder, and no need to write the service.